# Is there a way to force exact URL in XmlTypeAttribute.TypeName?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xml-attribute

I need to implement calls to some service that provider refuses and/or is unable to give WSDL for...

I have trouble with Serializing to XML.

URL in XmlTypeAttribute.TypeName gets encoded.

Since I got some XML examples from provider, I've tried generating classes with Edit=>Paste Special=>Paste XML As Classes, but it simply ignores "type".

I've created appropriate classes manually and everything works except the URL part.

I've checked: [C# Escaping XmlType Name with special char within XmlType() Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144363/c-sharp-escaping-xmltype-name-with-special-char-within-xmltype-attribute)
since it's quite similar, but my problem isn't in missing Namespace.

This is what I have for now:

```
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = @"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class Book
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Author;
    }

    [XmlType(TypeName = @"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText", Namespace = @"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class MyBookType : Book { }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(MyBookType))]
    [XmlRoot("Books", Namespace = @"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class Books : List<Book> { }

    public void Main()
    {
        var b = new Books();
        b.Add(new MyBookType
        {
            Title = "The Art of War",
            Author = "Sun Tzu"
        });
        b.Add(new MyBookType
        {
            Title = "Great Expectations",
            Author = "Charles Dickens"
        });

        var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Books));
        s.Serialize(Console.Out, b);
    }
```

XML which I'm expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <Book xsi:type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
    <Title>The Art of War</Title>
    <Author>Sun Tzu</Author>
  </Book>
  <Book xsi:type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">
    <Title>Great Expectations</Title>
    <Author>Charles Dickens</Author>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

XML which I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <Book xsi:type="http_x003A__x002F__x002F_docs.oasis-open.org_x002F_wss_x002F_2004_x002F_01_x002F_oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0_x0023_PasswordText">
    <Title>The Art of War</Title>
    <Author>Sun Tzu</Author>
  </Book>
  <Book xsi:type="http_x003A__x002F__x002F_docs.oasis-open.org_x002F_wss_x002F_2004_x002F_01_x002F_oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0_x0023_PasswordText">
    <Title>Great Expectations</Title>
    <Author>Charles Dickens</Author>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: The XML you are getting (and expecting) is not well-formed: the prefix `ns2:` on the element `<ns2:Security>` is not bound to a namespace.  Upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will see the error.  But I doubt your framework is actually generating malformed XML, probably something was left out of the question.  Can you share the XML you are actually getting, and actually want?

Comment: I tried test your code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SPkaQ1.  It doesn't compile because *The type or namespace name `BazaNS2PorukeXMLPHOBS<>` could not be found*.  Might you please [edit] your question to share a full [mcve] that we can test?

Comment: @dbc decided to put simpler example which should compile and run, thanks for pointing that out.